# How do I wire challenging bath situation

Tags: wiring, bathroom, switch, exhaust-fan

I have opened up my bath with studs and ceiling exposed. I have one power source going into the room.  I have :

1. Ventilation Fan/Light/Night light
2. 3 switch for one gang box
3. Vanity light that I wish tied to Main Light in Fan
4. Separate shower lights
5. Single switch for shower lights

I have 12/3 wire and 12/2 wire.

I know I'm going to split the power source to the shower light switch and to the 3 switch.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using only 12/2 and 12/3 cables like this.

[image]

Or you could use 12/2 and 12/4 cables like this.

[image]

Because there will be so many wires in the box, you'll want to get at least a 34 cu. in. double gang box.  Like [this one](http://m.homedepot.com/p/Carlon-2-Gang-35-cu-in-Electrical-Hard-Shell-Box-BH235AR/202077370/).

***NOTES:***

- *I've excluded grounding conductors from the images to increase clarity. Do not forget to connect all grounding conductors.*
- *These images assume the incoming power feeds into the switch box.*
- *These images assume that both switches are in the same box.*

Comment: That was very helpful.  That is exactly what I needed.  I;m going to try and fit all that in a double gang box since that is all I have room for.  I hope all the wiring will fit!

Comment: Look at the box, they typically list the max number of wires that can be placed into it.  If you have too many wires, try to find a deeper 2 gang box that will hold more wires.